# Add text to series of labels

Tags: jquery, html, label

I have a list of fields where the descriptions are inside label tags.
I want to add the Text "Your" before each label.

So far I have

```
<div id="field1">
    <label> First Label </label>
</div>
<div id="field2">
    <label> Second Label </label>
</div>
<div id="field3">
    <label> Third Label </label>
</div>
<div id="field4">
    <label> Fourth Label </label>
</div>
```

```js
var label = $("label");
$("label").html("Your"+ label.text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smftmdf1/1/

Any method to achieve this without using classes or Ids?

Comment: It's `.text()` => `$("label").html("Your"+ label.text());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Jquery function each to get the desired result.

```
var label = $("label");
$("label").each(function () {
    $(this).html("Your" + $(this).text())
});
```

Solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/7g7ycqnu/

Answer (score 2):

Just try with `.prepend()`

```
$('label').prepend('Your');
```

This is rather short and expressive + takes care of html if there is any.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/9amuu9fv/)**

Comment: Did you take a look at the [actual result](http://i.imgur.com/0Kf2fIP.png) that `prepend` causes? I'd say this is short and works, but not desired.

Comment: Yes it's strange, only in Chrome, not in FF for example.

Comment: I see! Alright, it's still a clever solution anyhow so I gave it a +1.

Comment: It's just that Chrome visualises text nodes by quotes, in IE dev toolbar you'll see the xml output `<TextNode />`. Haven't been able to merge them as clever as the actual answer. But then again, why is that bothering anyone? It won't be visible to the end user I assume. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not necessarily complaining, I'm here to learn (I'm a novice myself). But yeah, if the end user's view is what we focus on I guess there is no real issue, just me being a bit nitpicky.

Comment: oh you certainly can, always keep questioning ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't work as you provide the reference to `text`, not execute the function itself using `"Your"+ label.text()`. Note though, that this would only set all of the `label` elements with the same value.

To do what you require, you could provide a function to `text()`. This function will receive the current `text` value as the second parameter. As such you can just append `Your` to that value. Try this:

```
$('label').text(function(i, v) {
    return 'Your ' + v;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/smftmdf1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `each()` with `text()` instead of html. I also used a [id*="field"] identifier in the selector so that it only applies to labels inside divs with a `fieldx` id.

```js
$('[id*="field"] label').each(function(){
  $(this).text('Your '+ $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1">
    <label> First Label </label>
</div>
<div id="field2">
    <label> Second Label </label>
</div>
<div id="field3">
    <label> Third Label </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use    `.html( function )`

> function Type: Function( Integer index, htmlString oldhtml ) =>
>   htmlString A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the
>   index position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as
>   arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use
>   the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the
>   function, this refers to the current element in the set.

```
$("label").html(function(i,v) { 
 return 'Your ' + v;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/smftmdf1/3/)

Answer (score 0):

For your actual markup, there is a simple method to do this without using classes, id's or the jquery overhead.

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
//OR: var labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].textContent = 'Your' + labels[i].textContent;
    //OR: labels[i].innerHTML = 'Your' + labels[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Also, consider that bulk selection by tag name is not a best practice and depending on your document structure it can cause unwanted replacements. If you expect to have other tags (that you want preserved) inside labels, use the `innerHTML` property.